# special characters in XML file

Tags: xml

I am using an XML file in my application. I want to write my query string into the XML file and then read it from the application side. My query is like that:

```
select * from employee
where salary < 10000
```

I faced this problem: when I write this character `'<'` I got an error. How can I use it in my XML? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I ventured into queries. But, maybe you can use `CDATA`. Embed the special chars within it. This way the parser should skip it. See this: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from employee where salary &lt; 10000
```

Or you can use some `XML Document Writer` then you don't must write this string secure function by hand, your `XML Document Writer` code do this, and secure more characters who not allowed in `XML`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the "<" character using

```
&lt;
```

Somebody else beat me to it :)

You have to escape other characters too, see this question [Invalid Characters in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730133/invalid-characters-in-xml)

Answer (score 0):

In order to allow any special characters to be written in your xml file, make sure that you have the xml encoding defined at the top, like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```