# &oacute; not allowed in xml file but allowed in .net resource file?

Tags: asp.net, xml, resources, linq-to-xml

i'm parsing a few .net resource files (.resx).

In that, i have this piece of data:

```
informaci&oacute;n
```

This works in my .net app, but when i try to load this file in my xml document

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(s);
```

i get this error:

```
Reference to undeclared entity 'oacute'.
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&oacute;` is a [named HTML entity](http://www.fileformat.info/format/w3c/htmlentity.htm) that is not defined in XML.

XML only defines a subset of the named HTML entities (namely `&amp;`, `&apos;`, `&quot;`, `&gt;` and `&lt;` if memory serves).

You can use the numeric entity representation instead:

```
informaci&#243;n
```

Or, in hexadecimal:

```
informaci&#xf3;n
```

Comment: Hey thanks, i always thought the 2 meant the same, but that is probably only in html, and not in XML.

Comment: @Frederic So is it always safe to use the numeric entity representation in XML for any entity? or is there a subset in there as well?

Comment: @Matt, it's safe, *most of the time*. There are characters that cannot be used in XML, even in their numeric entity forms. The form feed character (`&#12;`) comes to mind, a complete list of *allowed* characters can be found in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5110103/464709).

Answer (score 3):

The entity oacute is not declared by default for XML.  Try `&#243;` instead.  [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) is a list of HTML entities with their corresponding codes, in case you have other similar problems.

If you'd prefer to continue using `&oacute;`, you can define the entity yourself.

If you are using a DTD, you can define it thus

```
<!ENTITY oacute "&#243;">
```

Or if using Schema, thus:

```
<xsd:element name="oacute" type="xsd:token" fixed="&#243;"/>
```