# An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0xc) was found

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

Parsing an XML file using the Java DOM parser results in:

```
[Fatal Error] os__flag_8c.xml:103:135: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0xc) was found in the element content of the document.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0xc) was found in the element content of the document.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There are a few characters that are dissallowed in XML documents, even when you encapsulate data in CDATA-blocks.

If you generated the document you will need to <strike>entity encode it or</strike> strip it out. If you have an errorneous document, you should strip away these characters before trying to parse it.

See dolmens answer in this thread: [Invalid Characters in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730133/invalid-characters-in-xml)

Where he links to this article: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets

Basically, all characters below 0x20 is disallowed, except 0x9 (TAB), 0xA (CR?), 0xD (LF?)

Comment: +1 - basically, the OP's problem is that the XML file he is trying to parse is invalid.

Comment: entity encoding won't work; the value simply isn't allowed in XML text

Comment: On UTF-8, the complete list of unallowed chars are these 5 hexa intervals: `0..8`, `B..C`, `E..1F`, `D800..DFFF`, `FFFE..FFFF`

Comment: @Topera are the ranges inclusive?

Answer (score 22):

```
public String stripNonValidXMLCharacters(String in) {
    StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer(); // Used to hold the output.
    char current; // Used to reference the current character.

    if (in == null || ("".equals(in))) return ""; // vacancy test.
    for (int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++) {
        current = in.charAt(i); // NOTE: No IndexOutOfBoundsException caught here; it should not happen.
        if ((current == 0x9) ||
            (current == 0xA) ||
            (current == 0xD) ||
            ((current >= 0x20) && (current <= 0xD7FF)) ||
            ((current >= 0xE000) && (current <= 0xFFFD)) ||
            ((current >= 0x10000) && (current <= 0x10FFFF)))
            out.append(current);
    }
    return out.toString();
}
```

Comment: If you could Write a Regex based solution that would be robust and fast

Comment: regex is generally slower, the above code would be faster since it only does this one thing

Comment: Now instead of  `StringBuffer` use `StringBuilder` because it is faster (does not require an Object monitor/is unsynchronized).

Answer (score 8):

Whenever invalid xml character comes xml, it gives such error. When u open it in notepad++ it look like VT, SOH,FF like these are invalid xml chars. I m using xml version 1.0 and i validate text data before entering it in database by pattern

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD\u10000-\u10FFF]+"); 
retunContent = p.matcher(retunContent).replaceAll("");
```

It will ensure that no invalid special char will enter in xml

Comment: The pattern you provide is correct, but does not compile as it is. You need some escaping. The correct is `Pattern.compile("[^\\u0009\\u000A\\u000D\\u0020-\\uD7FF\\uE000-\\uFFFD\\u10000-\\u10FFF]+")`

Answer (score 6):

The character 0x0C is be invalid in XML 1.0 but would be a [valid character in XML 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#NT-Char). So unless the xml file specifies the version as 1.1 in the prolog it is simply invalid and you should complain to the producer of this file.

Answer (score 4):

You can filter all 'invalid' chars with a custom FilterReader class:

```
public class InvalidXmlCharacterFilter extends FilterReader {

    protected InvalidXmlCharacterFilter(Reader in) {
        super(in);
    }

    @Override
    public int read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        int read = super.read(cbuf, off, len);
        if (read == -1) return read;

        for (int i = off; i < off + read; i++) {
            if (!XMLChar.isValid(cbuf[i])) cbuf[i] = '?';
        }
        return read;
    }
}
```

And run it like this:

```
InputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(xmlFile);
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileStream, charset));
InvalidXmlCharacterFilter filter = new InvalidXmlCharacterFilter(reader);
InputSource is = new InputSource(filter);
xmlReader.parse(is);
```

Comment: Hi Vadim, your idea is great. What is the source of XMLChar?

Comment: I found XMLChar on com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.XMLChar (inside Java 1.8)

Comment: java poi how to ignore these invalid characters? `Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileLocation);`

Answer (score 3):

On UTF-8, all the codes on these ranges are not allowed, for XML 1.0:

- 0..8
- B..C
- E..1F
- D800..DFFF
- FFFE..FFFF

A regex that can remove then is:

```
text.replaceAll('[\\x{0}-\\x{8}]|[\\x{B}-\\x{C}]|[\\x{E}-\\x{1F}]|[\\x{D800}-\\x{DFFF}]|[\\x{FFFE}-\\x{FFFF}]', "")
```

Note: if you are working with XML 1.1, you also need to remove these intervals:

- 7F..84
- 86..9F

Refs:

- XML 1.0 chars: https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets
- XML 1.1 chars: https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#charsets

Answer (score 1):

I just used this project, and found it very handy: https://github.com/rwitzel/streamflyer

Using the InvalidXmlCharacterModifier, as the documentation says.

Like this example:

```
public String stripNonValidXMLCharacters(final String in) {

  final Modifier modifier = new InvalidXmlCharacterModifier("",
    InvalidXmlCharacterModifier.XML_10_VERSION);

  final ModifyingReader modifyingReader = 
         new ModifyingReader(new StringReader(in), modifier);

  return IOUtils.toString(modifyingReader);
}
```

Comment: [Link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) are considered very low quality and [can get deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), please put the important parts from the linked resource into the answer body.

Comment: Hmm... just added an example @helvete

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue where XML was containing control characters. After looking into the code, I found that a deprecated class,StringBufferInputStream, was used for reading string content.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringBufferInputStream.html

```
This class does not properly convert characters into bytes. As of JDK 1.1, the preferred way to create a stream from a string is via the StringReader class.
```

I changed it to ByteArrayInputStream and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

For people who are reading byte array into String and trying to convert to object with JAXB, you can add "iso-8859-1" encoding by creating String from byte array like this:

String JAXBallowedString= new String(byte[] input, "iso-8859-1");

This would replace the conflicting byte to single-byte encoding which JAXB can handle. Obviously this solution is only to parse the xml.

Answer (score 0):

All of these answers seem to assume that the user is generating the bad XML, rather than receiving it from gSOAP, which should know better!

Comment: Then again, it could be a memory access issue that corrupts the content.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I've got a similar error:

`Servlet.service() for servlet [remoting] in context with path [/***] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: buildDocument failed.] with root cause
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 19; columnNumber: 91; An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0xc) was found in the value of attribute "text" and element is "label".`

---

After my first encouter with the error, I had re-typed the entire line by hand, so that there was no way for a special character to creep in, and Notepad++ didn't show any non-printable characters (black on white), nevertheless I got the same error over and over.

When I looked up what I've done different than my predecessors, it turned out it was one additional space just before the closing /> (as I've heard was recommended for older parsers, but it shouldn't make any difference anyway, by the XML standards):

`<label text="this label's text" layout="cell 0 0, align left" />`

When I removed the space:

`<label text="this label's text" layout="cell 0 0, align left"/>`

everything worked just fine.

---

So it's definitely a misleading error message.