# ErrorrAn invalid XML character (Unicode: 0xb) was found in the element content of the document while parsing xml with DOM parser

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, domparser

```
ErrorrAn invalid XML character (Unicode: 0xb) was found in the element content of the document.
```

I get this error when i am trying to parse an xml data using dom parser ?

What is the reason ?

How can i solve this problem ?

**EDIT**
Here is the XML file snippet

```
<CIRS><CIR applicantId="131906564" loanId="126907905" applicantRefId="TSFI012095G1" fan="TSFI012095"><REQUESTDATA><NAME>D DUNSTON JOSEPH WILFRED</NAME><DOB>31-07-1966</DOB><GENDER>Male</GENDER><ID><TYPE>PASSPORT NUMBER</TYPE><VALUE>H3359853</VALUE></ID><ID><TYPE>DRIVER'S LICENSE NUMBER</TYPE><VALUE>R/TN/69/005545/2005</VALUE></ID><PHONE>95412563#25,23778#34,87976#54</PHONE>
```

I guess the problem is in phone number tag `<PHONE>95412563#25,23778#34,87976#54</PHONE>`

Comment: can you show your xml? and how you parse it

Comment: It seems that your file is not XML. 0xb is a vertical tab. Perhaps you have some text in your XML that's not inside a XML element.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742543/an-invalid-xml-character-unicode-0xc-was-found?rq=1

Comment: am able to parse your xml successfully ..no exception..check the xml again

Answer (score 4):

Whenever invalid xml characters are entered into xml, it gives such an error. When you open it in Notepad++ it looks like VT, SOH, FF. These are invalid xml characters. I'm using xml version 1.0 and I validate text data before entering it in database by using the following pattern:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^\\u0009\\u000A\\u000D\u0020-\\uD7FF\\uE000-\\uFFFD\\u10000-\\u10FFF]+");
retunContent = p.matcher(retunContent).replaceAll("");
```

It will ensure that no invalid special character(s) will enter in xml.