# Code: USER_ERROR Details: Error Parsing XML: 0x5)

Tags: xml, netsuite, bfo

I have a problem with this error. Can anyone explain what this means?

```
Code: USER_ERROR
Details: Error Parsing XML: 0x5) was found in the element content of the document.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a invalid character `0x5` in the XML.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742543/an-invalid-xml-character-unicode-0xc-was-found) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730133/invalid-characters-in-xml)