# Need Some Quick Help With AN XML Parsing Error: not well-formed

Tags: xml

So This is the error I am getting:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: http://viralboss.us.to/km/
Line Number 4, Column 107:            <url>http://SOMEURL/ADE/FOKEO?sr=800&int=307200b&nvb=20110508013818&nva=20110508021818&hash=0732f9446b4f8a76dde35</url>
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

I have no idea why I am getting this error theres nothing wrong with my url can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

You can't place arbitrary text into an XML Element. The problem is that you need to escape your `&` sign. Use `&amp;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The & is an invalid character in XML. See this other question for how to escape the & sign.

[Invalid Characters in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730133/invalid-characters-in-xml)