# How to prevent Nokogiri from escape sequence replacement?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have a text node like so:

```
<string>Lorem Ipsum - All the &quot;facts&quot;.</string>
```

When I try to open and edit the document with this:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open(doc_name))
doc.search("//string[text() = '...']").remove
```

I get this in the actual document:

```
<string>Lorem Ipsum - All the "facts".</string>
```

Is there a way to save `&quot;` ??
Expected result:

```
<string>Lorem Ipsum - All the &quot;facts&quot;.</string>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756123/nokogiri-leaving-html-entities-untouched

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc_name = 'strings.xml'
output_file_name = "out.xml"
doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open(doc_name))
doc.search("//string[text() = '...']").remove
doc.search('//text()').each { |node| node.content = CGI.escape_html(node.text) }
end
File.write(output_file_name, doc.to_xml)
```

It simply escapes all text inside tags but keeps tags untouched.

Comment: it changes &quot; to &amp;quot;
in my case need to save &quot;

Comment: Oh, this can be a problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906705/how-to-save-unescaped-in-nokogiri-xml