# are characters # or & allowed in xml?

Tags: xml, ampersand

i have values with special chars that encoded to ascii in my xml.
for example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <name>&#381;irm&#363;n&#371;</name>
</response>
```

but when i parse value `name` i get only `&` as value. 
Is it allowed to use `#` or `&` in xml? or i have to use cdata necessarily?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The & character appears to be illegal, use (below) instead.

```
&amp;
```

[Invalid Characters in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730133/invalid-characters-in-xml)

The # character should be OK.

Also this may be useful: http://xml.silmaril.ie/specials.html.

Comment: so i have to set value &amp;#381;irm&amp;#363;n&amp;#371;??

Answer (score 6):

**&** needs to be escaped as it is used for esaping itself. All escapes start with **&** (`&quot;`, `&lt;`, `&gt;`).

**`&amp;`** is the escape for **&**

Comment: so i need to set value &amp;#381;irm&amp;#363;n&amp;#371;??