# An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line1, position 844

Tags: c#, xml

I have got the following exception from the below code block.

**An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line1, position 844.**

I was trying to parse s set of data retrieved from table to a data set.

```
public DataSet BindMasterData(string xml)
        {
            DataSet ds = null;
            try
            {
                ds = new DataSet();
                TextReader txtReader = new StringReader(xml);
                XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(txtReader);
                ds.ReadXml(reader);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new DataSet();
            }
            return ds;
        }
```

I have figured out the reason for the exception, but I couldn't solve it. In this particular situation, the string(which is retrieved from DB) contains a special character (&). That causes exception. How I can solve it. Any help on this would be great.

Comment: Please show the part of the document which causes the exception.

Comment: The string contains &. For Ex. A & B Constructions

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Just replace them:

Not valid in XML elements:

```
"   &quot;
'   &apos;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;
```

---

```
  public static string UnescapeXMLValue(string xmlString)
  {
    if (xmlString == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("xmlString")
    
    return xmlString.Replace("&apos;", "'").Replace("&quot;", "\"").Replace("&gt;", ">").Replace("&lt;", "<").Replace("&amp;", "&");
  }
 
 public static string EscapeXMLValue(string xmlString)
  {

    if (xmlString == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("xmlString")

    return xmlString.Replace( "&","&amp;").Replace("'","&apos;").Replace( "\"", "&quot;").Replace(">","&gt;").Replace( "<","&lt;");
  }
```

Comment: If you string the Replace function like that you can easily end up causing an error. e.g. "Dave's" would first become "Dave&apos;s" and would then become "Dave&amp;apos;s" which would display as "Dave&apos;s". This is seen frequently on some websites because someone made a mistake. I would suggest you don't try it using replace but instead look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331119/escape-invalid-xml-characters-in-c-sharp

Comment: Replace( "&","&amp;") should be call first in your method, otherwise something would happen like ">" turns into "&amp;gt;", it would be wrong.

Comment: `return xmlString.Replace("'","&apos;").Replace( "\"", "&quot;").Replace(">","&gt;").Replace( "<","&lt;").Replace( "&","&amp;");` - the last part will find the previously inserted `&` and replace them with `&amp`.

Comment: Replacing `"&amp;"` with `"&"` gave me the same error; only once I replaced with a regular string the parsing worked

Answer (score 25):

This has already been answered, but found a nicer way of achieving the same outcome by doing this in .NET 4.5 by using the Escape method as below:

```
var xmlWithEscapedCharacters = SecurityElement.Escape(xmlWithoutEscapedCharacters);
```

and then just plug that string into the XML that is being generated.

Link: [MSDN - SecurityElement.Escape Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityelement.escape(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Also worth noting this is also available for .NET Core https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(String)

Answer (score 1):

If your XML is being constructed with string concatenation then you'll be wanting to escape it.
`&` should become `&amp;` while `<` and `>` should become `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively.

There may be others too.
Of course you should really use a proper XML encoder rather than trying to do it yourself for many reasons.

Answer (score 1):

As the data comes from some data base, the problem can be hot-fixed in the context you described, but I would strongly recommend a different approach. The ampersand symbol should not have occured in the xml in the first place, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840981/are-characters-or-allowed-in-xml). Please clarify how the xml is generated and address the problem there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use: `SecurityElement.Escape(XML string)`

Reference link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityelement.escape(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Unfortinatly it make the same problem as common replace.
I tested it like  var tagText = SecurityElement.Escape("jsskhfkj & nln &amp;"); and get 
 - "jsskhfkj &amp; nln &amp;amp;". So you see that &amp; prodeses "&amp;amp;".