# I have got the following exception from the below code block. Error shows as being in Line 79

Tags: xml

My website is not being displayed and the below error is shown. Is it caused by incorrect characters ?

```
An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 2, position 1537.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Xml.XmlException: An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 2, position 1537.

Source Error:


Line 77:                 If strXML <> "" Then
Line 78:                     Dim rssDoc As New XmlDocument
Line 79:                     rssDoc.LoadXml(strXML)
Line 80: 
Line 81:                     Call Me.DateUpdated_Reset()



Stack Trace:


[XmlException: An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 2, position 1537.]
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e) +76
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg) +127
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseEntityName() +129
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseEntityReference() +50
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read() +623
   System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace) +786
   System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc) +53
   System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace) +171
   System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader) +109
   System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String xml) +113
```

Thanks for any help you can give

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541910/an-error-occurred-while-parsing-entityname-line1-position-844

Comment: Thanks. I did see that post, but I could not relate the solution to my issue. Is it obviously the same thing ?

Comment: You should show us your XML document, specifically the region around `Line 2, position 1537` as stated in the error message you got.

Comment: XML must be malformed or have a special character somewhere without being correctly escaped

Comment: Have you fixed your problem? If not try posting the xml string you are reading in that gives this error so we can better help you.