# how to escape special chars (invalid in xml) in Ant echo?

Tags: java, ant

I'm trying to do this in Ant:

```
<echo message="&#27;[44;1;37mSuccess!&#27;[m" />
```

But it doesn't work:

```
BUILD FAILED
./build.xml:92: Character reference "&#
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 0x1B character is invalid in XML contents ([Invalid Characters in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5110103/772981)). So you need some workaround. I would go with a javascript workaround, but I give also 2 additional solutions:

### javascript

```
<script language="javascript">
  project.setNewProperty("esc", "\u001b");
</script>
<echo>${esc}</echo>
```

### native2ascii

If you want the output in a file, then you could first output it using java escape `\u001b`, then convert it using reverse [Native2Ascii](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/native2ascii.html) routine. Regardless of the selected encoding it always decodes `\u` sequences.

```
<echo file="a.enc">\u001b</echo>
<native2ascii includes="a.enc" ext=".txt" dest="${basedir}"
              encoding="iso-8859-1" reverse="true" />
```

### property file

Finally you may have the unfortunate string constant in a file:

```
<property file="prop.txt" />
<echo>myEsc:${myEsc}</echo>
```

while the `prop.txt` contents is:

```
myEsc=\u001b
```

Comment: The `Character reference "&#` error occurs for `&#8;` (backspace) too. So the linked list of valid XML characters seems to be incomplete for ANT files.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use CDATA :

```
<project>

 <echo><![CDATA[
  &#27;[44;1;37mSuccess!&#27;[m
  ]]>
 </echo>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

& is a special character in ant, so you should replace it with '

```
<echo message="&amp;#27;[44;1;37mSuccess!&amp;#27;[m" />
```

Comment: You meant `&amp;` probably. But in this case I will see an ampersand in console, while I'm expecting `\x1b` (ESC symbol)