# Best PHP parser for invalid format xml

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

Whats the best xml parser to use especially for XML that's technically invalid format with the `<?xml` tag missing?

I cant use simpleXML because that gives a error for being invalid. I know i can manually add the tags I need after i get the xml but id prefer to see what you guys think is the best method for parsing a xml into an array in php.

Comment: if it's not valid xml, then technically it's not really xml... so don't look at an xml parser to handle what isn't really xml. expecting a chicken to be your banana isn't really useful.

Comment: ...most times i got such errors it was because of the "forbidden" XML characters, check here:         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730133/invalid-characters-in-xml

Comment: What do you mean by "technically invalid"? Not having an `<?xml` prologue is not enough by itself to make it invalid. What are the exact problems with the documents you're parsing? Could you show some examples of documents or error messages?

Comment: The document doesnt contain <?xml tag and also has some closing tags where the opening tag doesnt exist

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SimpleXML`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) and disable errors by using [`libxml_use_internal_errors(false);`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-errors.php). In case SimpleXML simply won't use your string, I've personally used [`DOM`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to parse/fix broken XML before.

On the other hand, why don't you simply add the `<?xml` characters before reading it?

Comment: thats what i was thinking but wasnt sure if that would be the best way. Also i tried using DOM but couldnt get it to work

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<?php
//invalid xml file
$xmlfile = 'test.xml';
$xmlparser = xml_parser_create();

// open a file and read data
$fp = fopen($xmlfile, 'r');
$xmldata = fread($fp, 4096);

xml_parse_into_struct($xmlparser,$xmldata,$values);

xml_parser_free($xmlparser);
print_r($values);
?>
```