# XLWorkbook : hexadecimal value 0x1D is invalid character ' on memory stream saving

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, closedxml

I am trying to download an excel file but keep getting

> hexadecimal value 0x1D is invalid character ' error

Please find my code below.

```
public static string GenerateRADownloadExcel(System.Data.DataTable downloadtable,long studyid, out string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        using (var wb = new XLWorkbook())
        {
            wb.Worksheets.Add(downloadtable);
            var raDataKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            fileName = "Study_" + studyid + "_ResearchActivityData_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyy") + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmm");

            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            wb.SaveAs(memoryStream);

            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            HttpContext.Current.Session[raDataKey] = memoryStream;

            return raDataKey;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

I get an exception on execution of `wb.SaveAs(memoryStream);`

Comment: @rene yes, [it does](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#ClosedXML/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/Excel/XLWorkbook.cs).

Comment: @CharlesMager I missed that this is ClosedXML ...

Comment: Have you got a stack trace that shows where in the bowels of ClosedXML this exception occurs?  It could relate to anything, really.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20103104/578411