# R.Java missing after adding a huge TextView to Activity

Tags: android, eclipse, textview, r.java-file

I'm trying to make an Activity that contains a huge TextView (a summary of a story or something), but when I define the String, my R.java disappears (because of the length).

I've tried to Project-> Clean, but it didn't help me.

What should I do to display that text ?

Comment: It should not be because of length. There should be some other issue.

Comment: if there is any resource whose name is equal to java reserved keyword like **int**, **double**, then R.java file will not be generated. for example you have added a image in your drawable folder with the name continue.png (here **continue** is java keyword), then R.java file will not be generated...

Comment: Also, have a look through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error which lists a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

R.java will not be generated if there is a syntax error in your strings.xml. The length is not the problem. There are probably characters that need to be [escaped in the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730133/invalid-characters-in-xml). The link is to an SO question about valid XML characters, and the accepted answer tells you what to look for and how to fix it.

Comment: I have no syntax error in my strings.xml. checked here .[link](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_validate.asp). no errors found. I cant find the problem.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but you can try the text piecemeal. Use only the first half of the text. If that works, use only the second half. Continue doing a binary search until you locate the problem.