# how to convert special characters to html data in xml?

Tags: php

[image]I am creating dynamic xml file to mysql data.
In that, Mysql data so many special character and &,<>...etc are there.

If you display these all things in browser,there is no problem it will display properly.

Coming to the xml, If you display in xml  it's showing errors.not displaying properly.In that content,so many special chars and unknown symbols are coming.If i display content in xml, i want to get pure content(human readable) same like as a html data.

can you please solve this problem...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invalid Characters in XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730133/invalid-characters-in-xml)

Answer (score 0):

use cdata in your xml

```
<xmltag><![CDATA[]]></xmltag>

<xmltag><![CDATA[" and ends with "]]></xmltag>
```

this will help you to solve your problem

Comment: I used <![CDATA[" and ends with "]]>. in that i want to break a line ..how ?

Comment: sorry dont understand your question

Comment: (" and ends with ") this your text you can use every thing breaking html tags " ' what ever you want

Comment: i want to remove this one ..<![CDATA[  empty  ]]> as above i mentioned in image.. @ Sohail Yasmin

Comment: can you send me link of your xml or sample xml that i can see where is the problem

Comment: that is in localhost..tell me your emaiil i will send that code

Comment: sohailyasmin1@gmail.com is my email address

Comment: message  me when you send me email

Comment: i have sent mail to u .@  Sohail Yasmin

Comment: hello did you get my mail