# Is closing tag ">" a valid character in xml?

Tags: c#, xml, validation, serialization, invalid-characters

*###################*

Update: thanks to user2622016 I relized the ">" is valid .

Now , in my c# code I have a class that one of its fields has ">" as its value.
I want to serialize the class to xml **WITHOUT** the ">" being escaped to  `&gt;` .
I am using xmlSerializer class. My code is:

```
 memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings();
                xmlWriterSettings.Encoding = encoding;
                xmlWriterSettings.Indent = true;
                System.Xml.XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, xmlWriterSettings);
                Serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, myObj);
```

any Idea How to achieve that without writing the entire XML using "writeRaw" (since i want the entire class to be serialized) ?

*###################*

is ">" a valid character in XML ?

simple answer is no . based on everything I know..
(also, [Invalid Characters in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730133/invalid-characters-in-xml) )

but when I am trying to check with xml validation tools available online
like: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp  , http://www.xmlvalidation.com/

it says the following xml is valid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<object>
   <innerObj attrib="myAttrib">invalid char is > why valid</innerObj >
</object>
```

How is it possible ?

(Reason i am asking , I am trying to take this xml as a class in c# and serialize it . obviously it escapes ">" to `"&gt;"` . and I don't want it to happen ..

Any explanation about this "Valid invalid" Character and how to solve my serialization issue ? )

Thanks!!!

Comment: Why you dont want it to be replaced? [Is is recommended to do that](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp)(see Entity References part)

Comment: "and I don't want it to happen" ... when you don't want valid XML, use something else.

Comment: look at @user2622016 answer , this is valid . it is on of the fields in my class and i want it to stay ">" when serialzing it .

Comment: Still cant understand the problem. When you serializing `>` it will be replaced to `&gt;` in your xml. When you deserialize it you will get `>` back. You want to see in xml `>`? But what you will do when you have `<>`?

Comment: **The right angle bracket (>) may be represented using the string "`&gt;`". Period.** It is up to the reader to interpret correctly both `>` and `&gt;` as just `>`. You want for aesthetic reasons it to be as is in plain text, right?

Comment: Maybe post another question on StackOverflow - *How to disable escaping > right angle bracket in C#*. Simply I don't know how.

Comment: You've said you want ">" not to be escaped, but you haven't said why. If there's a downstream process that can handle ">" but can't handle "&gt;", then that process is broken and needs fixing.

Answer (score 2):

Only ampersand (&) and the left angle bracket (<) characters cannot be used in text. The > 'greater than' is absolutely OK in xml text fields, because it does not make it ambiguous.
See chapter 2.4 http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#syntax

> The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) must not
>   appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters,
>   or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section. If
>   they are needed elsewhere, they must be escaped using either numeric
>   character references or the strings " & " and " < "
>   respectively. **The right angle bracket (>) may be represented using the
>   string "`&gt;`"**, and must, for compatibility, be escaped using either
>   "`&gt;`" or a character reference when it appears in the string " ]]>
>   " in content, when that string is not marking the end of a CDATA
>   section.

Why C# always escapes it as `&gt`? I don't know, maybe for some compatibility with some previous implementations?

According to the standard implementor may escape > as `&gt` if he wants to, but is required to do so only in combination `]]>`

Comment: Since it is valid , like you said. i want it to be written like it is and not be escaped , it is escaped when i am using the xmlSerializer class to serialize it from class object to xml.
code:
 memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings();
                xmlWriterSettings.Encoding = encoding;
                xmlWriterSettings.Indent = true;
                System.Xml.XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, xmlWriterSettings);
                Serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, myObj);

Answer (score 1):

You can use CDATA. Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<object>
  <innerObj attrib="myAttrib">invalid char is <![CDATA[>]]> why valid</innerObj >
</object>
```