# DTD Element Type to accept '<'

Tags: java, xml, dtd

I am having an xml file that may look like this:

```
<unclassified>
  WOOD FIRM FINED #30,000 OVER TEEN'S LOST ARM<
</unclassified>
```

.dtd declaration:

```
<!ELEMENT unclassified   (#PCDATA)>
```

Unfortunately this does not seem to work since I'm always getting an error like this:

```
[Fatal Error] arm1sub.sgml:14:46: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/sfalk/workspace/project/target/classes/meter_corpus/PA/annotated/courts/12.07.99/arm/arm1sub.sgml; lineNumber: 14; columnNumber: 46; The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:348)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:205)
```

How can I make this work? I hope this is somehow doable without manipulating my .xml files ..

Comment: This isn't a dtd problem - that's simply not well-formed XML. It would be broken without any dtd getting involved at all. You should be worried about whatever created the XML files.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730133/invalid-characters-in-xml/28152666

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is nothing you can change in the DTD to solve this problem.**  The "XML" document itself must be changed.  (Technically, your document is not even really XML.)

The purview of DTDs (and XSDs) is *validation*, but a prerequisite for XML being valid is for it to be *well-formed*.  (In fact, a prerequisite for a document being XML is that it be *well-formed*.)

Read [**Well-formed vs Valid XML**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085) for a thorough explanation of the differences.  For your particular problem, **replace `<` with `&lt;` to make your XML be *well-formed.***

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a value that contain invalid characters for xml parser you can use CDATA: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

```
<unclassified>
  <![CDATA[WOOD FIRM FINED #30,000 OVER TEEN'S LOST ARM<]]>
</unclassified>
```

or bay be you put a lower than that you didn't really want to...

```
<unclassified>
  WOOD FIRM FINED #30,000 OVER TEEN'S LOST ARM
</unclassified>
```