# Incorrect characters in resource files? (.resx, .resw)

Tags: .net, resources, resx

I am trying to investigate which characters could result in invalidity of resource file. Alas, I cannot find specification of these formats (resx, resw). I am not interested in syntax itself, but I know for sure, that there is set of characters, which makes resources invalid.

I am searching the internet for two hours now and so far I found just tutorials and articles, how to manipulate with resources. Does anyone have informations about this topic?

Thanks in regards for hints

Comment: It is a plain XML file, what characters are valid inside xml is well documented in many places.  Top google hit is [an SO Q+A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730133/invalid-characters-in-xml).

Comment: I recommend you [Zeta resources editor](http://www.zeta-resource-editor.com/index.html). This software helps me a lot when I'm editing resouce files.