# Why does android studio display an error message when we put '<' character in text of a button or a TextView?

Tags: android

This error causes other issues like it prevent the IDE from recognizing R class[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid Characters in XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730133/invalid-characters-in-xml)

Answer (score 2):

`<` is a character that you need to escape in xml. You need to write it as `android:text="&gt;"`

Refer to [What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents)

Answer (score 2):

Because there are some characters in XML that are not allowed in attributes. This is one of them. See also [this so entry that provides more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730133/invalid-characters-in-xml)