# XML - PIPE Character

Tags: xml, xslt, special-characters, email-templates

I have a `html` mail that is created via `xml`, for this reason I can't use some special characters [Invalid Characters in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730133/invalid-characters-in-xml).

So, how I can print the **|** ?

Comment: Going through the [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references), I haven't seen the | symbol anywhere. Are you sure you can't use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe character is `&#124;`
Hope it hels anyone in 2021. See here the full list: https://www.dvteclipse.com/documentation/svlinter/How_to_use_special_characters_in_XML.3F.html