# Swift write contents of XML that uses single quote: '

Tags: xml, swift, escaping, single-quotes

Swift 3

I am trying to write the contents of an XML file to disk but all my single quotes end up looking like **&apos** and not **'**. What do I need to do in order to get the single quotes to be written?

---

In this XML file, strings are always enclosed in single quotes, and arrays are comma separated.

This is the way an array of names must look when written:

```
<names value="'Fred', 'Wilma', 'George'"/>
```

And this is what I'm getting

```
<names value="&apos;Fred&apos;,&apos;Wilma&apos;,&apos;George&apos;/>
```

---

Comment: The single quote is an invalid character in an XML attribute, and is escaped as "XML character reference" `&apos;` , see for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/730150/1187415.

Answer (score 0):

Solved

Martin R's reminder was all I needed to figure out a way to deal with the situation.

I just treated the xml as a literal string and used brute force.

```
let newXML = xmlAsString.replacingOccurrences(of: "&apos;", with: "'")
```

Thanks!