# vb.net XML enconding "&" to "&amp;" in UTF-8

Tags: xml, vb.net, utf-8

I'm using MS XmlWriter for creating a XML file in UTF-8.

```
Dim settings As New XmlWriterSettings()

settings.Indent = True
settings.IndentChars = "    "
settings.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8      
settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment

Using xWriter As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(filePath, settings)
```

If I try to write using `WriteElementString` with the value of `&` I get `&amp;` in the output XML. In UTF-8 shouldn't it stay as "&"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid Characters in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730133/invalid-characters-in-xml)

Answer (score 1):

Escaping of special characters has nothing to do with encoding. Whether your encoding is UTF-8 or anything else, `&` and `<` must always be escaped in XML.

Answer (score 0):

`&` is an illegal character in XML and must be escaped. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/730150/4397397