# Handle HTML tags from XML in mapforce

Tags: html, xml, html-table, map-force

I'm having trouble with html-table in xml with mapforce.
It looks like mapforce removes HTML tags and that makes the output unstructured.

I posted this on Altova forum also where you can get the files: https://www.altova.com/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&t=1100001859

Tried various fuctions (tokenize etc.) to identify the tags, but it's seems like they're allready gone.

Anybody knows how to handle HTMLcode from XML with mapforce correctly?
Input files are from external source, so we can't change them unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I gave a look to your output XSD: TEST_html_out-2.xsd, and I found that your output element is:

```
<xs:element name="MakroMikroBeskrivelse" type="xs:anyURI"/>
```

The output type is described there: http://books.xmlschemata.org/relaxng/ch19-77009.html and thre http://www.datypic.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_anyURI.html
and it is stripping the whitespace. This explain why your output does not look well formatted.

I would recommend you to use another data-type, xsd:string for example.
http://www.datypic.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_string.html

You have to note that if you are using xs:string in your output schema, your HTML tag will be escaped.

You have a bit more details there:
[Invalid Characters in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730133/invalid-characters-in-xml)

Let us know if it helps your to solve your issue!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Part of the problem is as you put it that HTML tags will be escaped. That is where the structure is defined (whitespace, newline etc.). I got 2 solutions to keep HTML table for altova forum (copy all and dynamic nodes), but we can't do direct transfer for this element unfortunataly. I'm working on a manual fix with insert char-from-kode-10 (newline) with before and after substrings of node names. Not that straigth forward, but looks like it will work.