# Finding invalid XML/SQL characters in SQL using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `TableName` with a column `Characters`.

In the `Characters` column I have the following data with some others that need to be checked as well as these:

```
Apples
15
chocolate
afternoon
Joe & taffy
@fternoon
^up
(here)
`til
```

I want to have a SQL script that would allow me to find any characters in that column that would be invalid for `XML` or `SQL`. Sort of like a `patindex`.

So I would like this to show something like this:

Joe & Taffy, line number 5, 4th character

@fternoon, line number 6, 1st character

D'antonio, line number 452, 2nd character

Ch@rles', line number 947, 3rd character and 8th character.

Comment: sample output scenario would be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If try_convert is supported by your version of MS SQL Server?
Then you can try to convert the string to an XML.
If TRY_CONVERT couldn't convert to XML, then it would return NULL.

And you can use a character set `[...]` in a PATINDEX.
If you'd want to locate the first position of the usual suspects.

**Example :**

```
declare @TestTable table (id int identity(1,1) primary key, Characters varchar(30));

insert into @TestTable (Characters) values
('Apples'),('15'),('chocolate')
,('@fternoon'),('^up'),('(here)'),('`til')
,('after < noon')
,('Joe & taffy')
;

select *, patindex('%[&<]%',Characters) as FirstBadCharPosition
from @TestTable
where try_convert(XML,concat('<x>',Characters,'</x>')) is null;
```

**Result:**

```
id  Characters      FirstBadCharPosition
--  ----------      --------------------
8   after < noon    7
9   Joe & taffy     5
```

Comment: The question lies with data that is unknown so as an example,
I listed a few things from the column. There are hundreds of more items in that table besides apple, 15, chocolate etc..
I need it to look through everything without me having to insert into if that makes sense. 
Shouldnt the result show the ' for the til also?

Comment: If you read [this older SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730133/invalid-characters-in-xml) and the answers then you notice that the are only a few characters that have to be escaped with `xml entities` for  XML compliance. F.e. `&` to `&amp;`.  And there are unicode ranges for valid characters in the [xml specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets).  And normally the XML data type in Sql Server wouldn't accept invalid xml.

Comment: Is there a way to get that result but without listing everything in the column? So make it look at everything in the column.