# Java: How to output a string when the string contains null character?

Tags: java, string

My code utilizes XMLwriter and XMLObjectOutputStream to process with string.

The key point is the string may contain **character zero (\0)**. If I use `string.replace("\0", "")` there is no error reported. 
If do not use `string.replace("\0", "")`, it will report "character zero is not allowed in output".

However, I need to keep the original string so can use it next to output into a txt file. In this case, how to deal with the string to keep the \0 and also work with XMLwriter?

The string looks like:

```
 NULNULSTX &The story of Florida
```

(open in Notpad++ shows NUL, open in txt just show space in NUL)

Here is the error info:

```
ERROR (SelectorManager.run):  java.lang.IllegalStateException: character zero is not allowed in output
at org.xmlpull.mxp1_serializer.MXSerializer.writeAttributeValue(MXSerializer.java:849)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1_serializer.MXSerializer.attribute(MXSerializer.java:624)
```

Also, if the string cannot escape from null terminate, can we find another way to replace string (e.g. char, array...) to output the original info?

Comment: Do you have the same problem with `<` and `>` in the text? Then your problem is escaping. You must escape strings to be compatible with xml.

Comment: I do not have the problem with < or >, only with null character which makes me confusing. Now it seems need to find a way to keep the null character in string, or use other formats to store the context?

Comment: Maybe this explains why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730133/invalid-characters-in-xml. Have you tried putting it into a CDATA section. Please post a simple code example that fails. It is easier to check the validity of answers if one could test it directly on the code you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution, it seems we can utilize **StringEscapeUtils** in **java.commons.lang3**.

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(javaString)
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(javaString)
```

that can encode the string without violating the XML requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than replacing the "\0" with an empty string, try escaping it with an escape character:

```
string.replace("\0", "\\0")
```

Comment: After output the string into a txt file, it shows \0 in the string which different with the original (null). The key is need to keep the sting same as before...

Comment: As @CoronA commented, it would be easier to help with an example of what string is failing and what you're expecting the output to be for that string.

Comment: I edit the original text, please see the details. Thanks

Comment: If you just need it to be human readable why not replace the '\0' with 'NUL'?  You lose the actual character but the text will be the same across any editor.

Comment: The key point is the string needs to be kept as exactly as before, and it will be used in the next to do some operations....so I cannot just replace \0 with nul...