# How to prevent CXF from converting %gt; to > in payload?

Tags: xml, apache-camel, cxf

I have a camel adapter with a CXF enpoint for the input (from) that is configured like this:

```
  <camel-cxf:properties>
    <entry key="dataFormat" value="PAYLOAD"/>
    <entry key="allowStreaming" value="true"/>
    <entry key="relayHeaders" value="false"/>
  </camel-cxf:properties>
```

The SOAP input contains the following element in the payload:

```
<foo>here is an arrow -&gt;</foo>
```

However the output looks like this:

```
<foo>here is an arrow -></foo>
```

I know it's not invalid. XML does not require to escape >. It is "only" highly recommended (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28152666/1421505) for details).

**But I do not want the payload being altered. CXF should only cut off the SOAP envelope and keep everything in it as it was. Can I disable parsing/re-serialization of the XML payload?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mine found out, that the problem seems to be how other components work with CXF's **CachedCxfPayload** output object. The processor that comes after CXF seems to do the unwanted conversion.

Our solution is to convert CXF's output into a string before passing it on:

```
<convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
```

Now there's no conversion anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at adding an interceptor (as last step of the receive), or you could pass it into a processor in the camel route, after the cxf step and modify the body.

[CXF Interceptor](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the dataFormat to MESSAEG, in this way camel-cxf will not get touch with the XML payload or the attachments.
BTW, you cannot access the SOAP Header with this dataFormat.

Comment: Thank you. However, I need to access the SOAP header, so I will look for a different solution.