# Python ElementTree generate not well formed XML file with special character '\x0b'

Tags: python, xml, special-characters, non-well-formed

I used `ElementTree` to generate xml with special character of '\x0b', then use `minidom` to parse it. It will throw `not well-formed` error.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.dom import minidom
root = ET.Element('root')
root.text='\x0b'
xml = ET.tostring(root, 'UTF-8')
print(xml)
pretty_tree = minidom.parseString(xml)
```

**Generated XML**: `<root>\x0b</root>`

**Error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testXml.py", line 7, in <module>
    pretty_tree = minidom.parseString(xml)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1968, in parseString
    return expatbuilder.parseString(string)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 925, in parseString
    return builder.parseString(string)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 223, in parseString
    parser.Parse(string, True)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 6
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behaviour has been raised as a [bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue5166) in the past and resolved as "won't fix".

The author of the ElementTree module [commented](https://bugs.python.org/issue5166#msg89685)

> For ET, [this behaviour is] very much on purpose.  Validating data provided by every
> single application would kill performance for all of them, even if only a
> small minority would ever try to serialize data that cannot be represented
> in XML.

The closing [comment](https://bugs.python.org/issue5166#msg340981) (by the maintainer of [lxml](https://lxml.de), who is also a Python core dev) includes these observations:

> This is a tricky decision. lxml, for example, validates user input, but that's because it has to process it anyway and does it along the way directly on input (and very efficiently in C code). ET, on the other hand, is rather lenient about what it allows users to do and doesn't apply much processing to user input. It even allows invalid trees during processing and only expects the tree to be serialisable when requested to serialise it.
>
> I think that's a fair behaviour, because most user input will be ok and shouldn't need to suffer the performance penalty of validating all input. Null-characters are a very rare thing to find in text, for example, and I think it's reasonable to let users handle the few cases by themselves where they can occur.
>
> ...
>
> In the end, users who *really* care about correct output should run some kind of schema validation over it *after* serialisation, as that would detect not only data issues but also structural and logical issues (such as a missing or empty attribute), specifically for their target data format. In some cases, it might even detect random data corruption due to old non-ECC RAM in the server machine. :)
>
> ...

So in summary, `ET.tostring` will generate xml which is not well-formed, and this is by design.  If necessary, the output can be parsed to check that it is well-formed, using `ET.fromstring` or another parser.  Alternatively, lxml can be used instead of ElementTree.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanations. It's unfortunate. Many times we use XML as a generic data serialization format, we can't control what's the underlying data. In my case, I spend hours troubleshooting a bug that serializes a large user input data (few MB). The error message in the parser didn't tell me the correct location. So I have to do a binary search until I find this issue. This seems to be a problem with XML Spec which put an unnecessary restriction on accepted charset.

Answer (score 1):

`\x0b` is an XML restricted character.  There is a good description of valid and restricted characters in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730133/what-are-invalid-characters-in-xml).

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround for myself, I wrote a helper method to clean the restricted chars before saving to XML model:

```py
def clean(str):
  return re.sub(r'[^\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD\u10000-\u10FFF]+', '', str)
```