# \u000b and other Control Unicode Characters not compatible with docx4j?

Tags: java, docx4j

Adding a text that has the unicode "\u000b" will throw an error when you open the saved docx.

I am using docx4j-JAXB-Internal 8.1.6. The same issues occurs with "\u000c" so I assumed it happens with all Control Characters. At the moment I am simply removing them with:

```
        String removeControlCharacters = this.content.replaceAll("\\p{Cc}", "");
```

and then adding it a Text and it works fine.

I am wondering if anyone else has had this issue and what the best way to resolve it is.

Comment: U+000B and U+000C are two of several characters that can't appear in XML, even if escaped.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730133/what-are-invalid-characters-in-xml ; see also: https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-charref.

Comment: open the file with notepad and set the encoding to UTF without BOM