# Escaped apostrophe in XML attributes, using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Probably being stupid, but is there a way to include an escaped apostrophe in an xml attribute using xslt?

As far as I understand, characters like the apostrophe are valid in xml *elements*, but not in their *attributes*.  As a result, I'm trying to escape `'` to `&apos;` in the output - but I'm running into a bit of bother.

I've tried all sorts, like using `xsl:text/disable-output-escaping`, `&#39;`, `CDATA` (among others) and the closest I've been able to get is to double escape the ampersand like this: `&amp;apos;`

But I think this means I'm left with the character for an ampersand and separately, the text `apos;`, rather than the proper `&apos;` I'm after.

---

**Input xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<boof>
    <moo></moo>
</boof>
```

**Current XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="moo">
        <xsl:element name="moo">
            <xsl:attribute name="att">&amp;apos;</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

**Current output**

```
<boof>
    <moo att="&amp;apos;"/>
</boof>
```

---

**Desired output**

```
<boof>
    <moo att="&apos;"/>
</boof>
```

Comment: You can use apostrophes in attribute values just like any other character, unless you use it as the delimiter for the attribute value instead of double quotes.

Comment: Thanks!  I think I'd misread some of the material I'd read elsewhere - I thought that apostrophes were plain invalid when in attributes.

Comment: In XSLT you can concentrate on getting the structure (of the result tree) right. The XSLT processor will look after making sure that it's serialized correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to include an escaped apostrophe in an xml attribute using xslt?

No. Whether a character is escaped or not is immaterial.

`<moo att="'" />` and `<moo att="&apos;" />` are *exactly the same thing*. They describe identical nodes, once the document is parsed they will be indistinguishable.

If you have code that relies on `&apos;` being there, that code is broken and that's the code you need to fix.

The following will all produce the same result:

```
<xsl:template match="moo">
    <xsl:element name="moo">
        <xsl:attribute name="att">&apos;</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

or, for short

```
<xsl:template match="moo">
    <xsl:element name="moo">
        <xsl:attribute name="att">'</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

or, even shorter

```
<xsl:template match="moo">
    <moo att="'" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Ah, right that simplifies things a lot then, thanks!  There's no specific broken code at the minute, I just wanted to make sure I was outputting valid xml.  I'd just seen conflicting information stating that the ' character was invalid, like the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730133/what-are-invalid-characters-in-xml).

I can see now that it's only "strongly advised" when not using characters of the same type.

Comment: @Mal The `'` character is valid anywhere, except in attributes that are enclosed in single quotes (`att='...&apos;...'` encodes `...'...`). The same applies to the `"` character (`att="...&quot;..."` encodes `..."...`). The escape sequences `&apos;` and `&quot;` are only really necessary in these circumstances. But of course they work everywhere, so you would not invalidate your document by using `&apos;` every time you want to refer to a single quote. The XSLT processor decides whether it uses the literal or the escaped variant in attributes. It won't mess this up.