# How to add escape characters in URLRewrite

Tags: lucee, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I would like to add the following rule in my urlrewrite.xml (Lucee server):

```
<from>^([a-zA-Z0-9\/\-\%\+:\[\]\{\}\|\;\<\>\?\,\*\!\@\#\$\ \(\)\^_`~]*)$</from>
<to type="passthrough">/index.cfm?furl=$1</to>
```

but unfortunately i receive an error regarding **<** character. For your better assistance, i attach the following image:

[image]

Any idea that could help me?

Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are invalid characters in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730133/what-are-invalid-characters-in-xml)

Comment: You have one large character set definition set inside square brackets [ ] and you are escaping lots of charachters inside, such as dot, asterisk and many more. MetaCharacters inside character sets are very different from the ones ouside: Only MetaCharacters that need to be escaped are the closing bracket ], the backslash \ and the caret ^. All others are considered being natural characters, hence you won't need to escape all of these. Please see "Metacharacters Inside Character Classes" in https://regular-expressions.mobi/charclass.html?wlr=1

Comment: Yes your article was indeed very helpful for invalid XML characters. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're putting invalid characters in your XML value.

This is what it should be:

```
<from>^([a-zA-Z0-9\/\-\%\+:\[\]\{\}\|\;\&lt;\&gt;\?\,\*\!\@\#\$\ \(\)\^_`~]*)$</from>
```

These characters need to be escaped in XML:

```
&
'
"
<
>
```

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML